Check the Retrieves Job done on my AWS S3 Glacier Deep archive
There is a job done by a user, who said that he has retrieved one file, however, the cost is huge of the retrieval activity.
I want a way to know the details of the retrieval jobs done on the s3 bucket and check if it was a file retrieval or an entire folder retrieval.

Look in the S3 batch operations page. It's in the S3 area as per picture attached. Link - make sure the region selected matches your bucket if you can't see is.

